# Pimcore: How to sort a data object listing by data object modification date?

Tags: pimcore

As simple as the title...

PS: this does not work

```
$news = new News\Listing();
$news->setOrderKey("o_modificationDate");
$news->setOrder("DESC");

Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'o_modificationDate' in 'order clause'
```